# How add tooltips to modeless dialogue in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am working on MFC dll Using MFC in a Shared DLL.Can any one help me how i can achive ??

I am creating tooptip in OnInitDialog using create and AddTool

PreTranslateMessage is also called but It is not working for me. I see no tooltips and get no errors/assertions/exceptions anywhere
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just out of curiosity: have you added the chunk of code similar to this one: `if (m_pToolTip != NULL) m_pToolTip->RelayEvent(pMsg);`, as it is suggested by MSDN?

Comment: Ya I have added this line in PreTranslateMessage. This line is called and no error but no effect. I cant see tooltips.if u have working code it will hepl me lot.